# Difference between a positive cubic meter and an inverse cubic meter?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

In science I commonly see the notation $m^{3}$ and $m^{-3}$, especially when discussing the amount of molecules in a volume.
What is the difference between those two units?     For example, does $1.5\times 10^{10}\ m^{-3}$ translate into $10^{10}$ molecules per $m^3$ of air?

Comment: More or less. $1.5\times 10^{10}m^{-3}$ in this context  means that you have $1.5\times 10^{10}=15,000,000,000=\text{15 Billion}$ molecules per $m^3$ air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$m^3$ is units of cubic meters. $m^{-3}$ is *inverse* cubic meters (not *negative*), meaning something **per meter**. So if I say the number of grains of sand on the beach is $10^{10}m^{-3}$, what I am really saying is that every cubic meter contains $10^{10}$ grains of sand, or that the density of the sand is $10^{10}$grains$/m^3$.

Full disclosure: I know nothing about sand. That number is probably way off. I would count them, but not even ***I*** can count that much.

Note, *negative* cubic meters would just be $-m^3$.

Comment: "*Note, negative cubic meters would just be −m*". How can I phrase my question to avoid mis-understanding? Thanks

Comment: I think you are fine. You asked your question, and part of the question involved being unsure of terminology. Do you feel like it has been sorted out now?

Comment: perhaps change "negative" to "inverse" in the title, or something, if you feel like you should.

Answer (score 1):

The negative in the exponent means it is per cubic meter. You can think of it placing the cubic meters in the denominator.

Comment: If negative exponent translates into *per cubic meter*, what does a positive exponent translate into? i.e. $1.5\times 10^{10}\ m^{3}$

Comment: It just means cubic meters.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between these units is more or less the same as for two different measures of fuel consumption cars:

- In the US, it is typically measured as "Miles per Gallon".
- In Germany, it is measured as "Litre per 100 km".

If you get rid of the different units, it is "km per litre" vs. "litre per km".